# How do I generate the source code to create an object I'm debugging?

Tags: java, testing, code-generation, automated-tests

Typical scenario for me:

1. The legacy code I work on has a bug that only a client in production is having
2. I attach a debugger and figure out how to reproduce the issue on *their* system given *their* input.  But, I don't know why the error is happening yet.
3. Now I want to write an automated test on my local system to try and reproduce then fix the bug

That last step is really hard.  The input can be very complex and have a lot of data to it.  Creating the input by hand (eg: `P p = new P(); p.setX("x"); p.setY("x");` imagine doing this 1000 times to create the object) is very tedious and error prone.  In fact you may notice there's a typo in the example I just gave.

**Is there an automated way to take a field from a break point in my debugger and generate source code that would create that object, populated the same way?**

The only thing I've come up with is to serialize this input (using Xstream, for example).  I can save that to a file and read it back in in an automated test.  This has a major problem: If the class changes in certain ways (eg: a field/getter/setter name is renamed), I won't be able to deserialize the object anymore.  In other words, the tests are extremely fragile.

Comment: Could you clarify why something like XStream doesn't fit and why you absolutely need to generate source code? This would certainly help to get better answers.

Comment: What's the issue with long-term fragility of test cases for a field test event you want to solve NOW?

Comment: @IraBaxter There's nothing wrong with that for the short term. But if there's some cool library/technique/strategy out there to deal with this better than I currently am, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Can you explain what you don't like about the reflection approach?

Comment: @assylias Many reasons.  For one, it doesn't get the setters correctly (`m[i].toString()` will start w/ public/private, not the method name), it literally passes "(value)" to the setters, it doesn't traverse the object tree and I suspect it won't handle Collections correctly.

Comment: @assylias Don't get me wrong, Reflection may be the answer here.  But if it is, I'm hoping someone else already solved these problems for me and put them in a library I can reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java standard serialisation is well know to be not very usefull when objects change their version ( content, naming of fields). Its fine for quick demo projects.

More suitable for your needs, is the approach that objetcs support your own (binary) custom serialisation:
This is not difficult, use `DataOutputStream` to write out all fields of an object. But now introduce versiong, by first writing out a `versionId`. Objects that have only one version, write out versionId 1. That way you can later, when you have to introduce a change in your objetcs, remove fields, add fields, raise the version number.

Such a `ICustomSerializable` will then first read out the version number from the input stream, in a readObject() method, and depending on the version Id call readVersionV1() or e.g `readVersionV2().`

```
public Interface ICustomSerializable {
  void writeObject(DataOutputStream dos);
  Object readObject(DataInputStream dis);
}

public Class Foo {
  public static final VERSION_V1 = 1;
  public static final VERSION_V2 = 2;

  public static final CURRENT_VERSION = VERSION_V2;
  private int version;

  private int fooNumber;
  private double fooDouble;

  public void writeObject(DataOutputStream dos) {
     dos.writeInt(this.version);
      if (version == VERSION_V1) {
          writeVersionV1(dos);
      } else (version == VERSION_V2) {
          writeVersionV2(dos);
      } else {
         throw new IllegalFormatException("unkown version: " + this.version);
      }
  }
  public void writeVersionV1(DataOutputStream dos) {
        writeInt(this.fooNumber);
        writeDouble(this.fooValue);
  }
}
```

Further getter and setter, and a constructor with initialised the version to CURRENT_VERSION is needed.

This kind of serialisazion is safe to refactoring if you change or add also the appropriate read and write version. For complex objects using classes from external libs not und your controll, it can be more work, but strings, lists are easily serialized.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  In fact, I was thinking of writing my own xstream serializer to write the source code out (if that's even an option).  The thing I don't like about this suggestion is the build breaking will probably be the thing that notifies me I've gotta implement `writeVersionV2`. I wouldn't want to write it under that condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is store the "state", and then restore that in your test to ensure the bug stays fixed.

Short answer: There is afaik no such general code generation tool, but as long as several constraints are kept, writing such a tool is small work.

Long Comment:
There are constraints under which that can work. If everything is just beans with getter and setter for all the fields you need, then generating code for this is not so difficult. And yes that would be safe to renaming if you refactor the generated code along with the normal code. If setter are missing, then this approach will not work. And that is only one example of why this is no general solution.

Refactoring can also for example move fields to other classes. How do you want to introduce the values from the other fields of that class? How can you later know if they that altered your saved state still reflects the critical data? Or worse, imagine the refactoring gives the same field a different meaning than before.

The nature of the bug itself is also a constraint. Imagine for example the bug happened because a field/method had this and that name. If a refactoring now changes the name the bug will not appear anymore regardless your state.

Those are just arbitrary examples, that may have exactly nothing to do with your real life cases. But this is a case to case decision, not a general strategy. Anyway, if you know your code the bug and your refactorings are all well behaving enough for this, then making such a tool is done in less than day, probably much less.

With xstream you would partially get this as well, but you would have to change the xml yourself. If you used for example db4o you would have to tell it that this and that field has now this and that name.