# A Java function to Generate Mock data CODE by taking a Java Object

Tags: java, reflection, mockito

Is there a Java function to Generate Mock data CODE by taking a Java Object? The output uses the existing setter but not constructor.
Say such a function named `void Generate(Class<T> klazz)`

```
Generate(person);//person is a POJO with data in it.
```

This will sysout the following in stdout.

```
Person mockPerson = new Person;
mockPerson.setName("name");
mockPerson.setAge(1);
```

I believe this may take advantage of Java Reflection.

Comment: what is the use case you are looking to address?

Comment: I am trying to mock data using Mockito and the data needs to be exactly like the actual data in runtime inside other project. I am using breakpoint to look at the actual data in the Java Object and copy it to the mock Java Object. If you know what I mean.

Comment: What I don't understand is why not just use the actual object? 
person = new Person(); person.setName("foo"); person.setAge(bar);

Comment: Because it is coming from the other project.

Comment: So what? What exactly prevents you from instantiating it?
I mean, you *can* do something like: person = mock(Person); 
when(person.getName()).thenReturn("foo"); when(person.getAge()).thenReturn(1);
But I don't see *why* you would want to do something like this instead of simply instantiating the object.

Comment: In the other project. There is no object initialization code for me to copy over since it's getting data from database and the object itself is instantiated by dependency injection. I will be mocking hundreds of objects. Better let Java generate the code for me.

Comment: Where will the generated code get the data from?

Comment: The object itself in runtime.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you already have an object, why do you need to mock it???

Comment: @Dima: Its relevant in following scenario: Maybe a user finds a bug in my code. He sends a description how to reproduce. I track the bug down to object Person. Now I want to write a unit test for this test data (to prevent further bugs). Since the Person Class could be complex It would be fine, that some tool could serialize the complete state of the test object to file.

Comment: I think this question is simlar, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336224/serialize-object-for-unit-testing , however they did not find a solution

Comment: @StefanA do you mean the data would be included into the report from the user (otherwise, I still don't understand where it would come from to get into the "tool")? 
If you make your class Serializable, you could store its state into a binary file to restore it later. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: My thoughts: I know the location of the error and I know the object that causes the error, I dont know the state of this object. So I want to serialize this object (after logging the error). I could indeed use the java serializer. But reloading a serialized object in a unit test is a problem, since it gets invalid if I change this class (which is probable if it contains bugs). So the serialization should contain a sequence of constructors/setters that lead to the object. It is human readable, insertable into a unit test and even changeable, if the class changes.

Comment: @StefanA That's exactly my problem.